# My disc drive does not recognize some (known-working) discs

Tags: drivers, disk, ripping

I'm running Linux Mint 18.2. I have an Asus Blu-Ray drive, marked as also being able to read DVDs and CDs. I have two music CDs and two data CDs to which I have immediate access, and which I have confirmed it is able to read. I also have quite a lot of other discs which it cannot read – `dd` from the relevant device responding identically to when there is no disc at all in the drive. The other discs are all console games – Wii, Wii U, and PS2 – which I wanted to rip for backup and ease-of-use purposes. I could understand a failure to read discs for the two Nintendo systems, since from what I could tell they use proprietary DVD-based-but-not-DVD formats, but everything I can find says the PS2 used ordinary DVDs (and CDs) and I can't find anyone saying ripping such a game would be difficult. I have confirmed on the relevant systems that the game disks themselves are not damaged, or at least not so badly damaged that the games do not start.

Is this potentially some kind of driver issue? A disc drive problem preventing DVD reading but not CD reading? (I don't have any non-game DVDs on hand to check). Something else?